# Largest 3 numbers c language

Tags: c

I need to enter 10 numbers and it should display the largest 3 out of them.But so far i can only find the largest one. Can someone help me to find the largest 3 numbers please.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
  int num[10], grt, i = 0, j = 1;
  printf("\nEnter 10 numbers ");
  for(; i < 10; i++, j++)
  {
    printf("\nEnter next number %d : ", j);
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
  }
  grt = num[0];
  i = 0, j = 1;

  for(; i < 9; i++)
  {
    if(grt < num[i + 1])
    {
      grt = num[i + 1];
    }
  }

  printf("\nLargest 3 numbers are : %d", grt);
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Find the largest, knock it off the list, repeat 2 more times.

Comment: Sort the array and then extract the largest `n` numbers you want.

Comment: Is this homework, are you restricted not to use `qsort`

Comment: Initialize the array element first with 0.

Comment: IMHO, you only need to store the 3 biggest values (not all 10) and each time you read a new one - just compare/shirt/replace them.

Comment: there are three types of sorts. Bubble, insertion and selection sort. try all three. lots of eg.s on the web

Comment: @csaw *three types of sort*? Are you serious?

Comment: Still trying to sort it out any other options?

Comment: A flaw in your code: You try to assign `grt` to `num[0]` which is an uninitialized location. This leads to UB. Fix it by setting `i=0` before the first loop

Comment: Have to agree with @Alex. If spec say you should print 3 biggest from 10 inputs, then keep track of three largest at any time. If you are meant to keep entire array (10 items) then ask for a better spec ;) In short: `if (digit > num[2]) { num[1] = num[2]; num[2] = d; }` etc. If you are supposed to keep all 10 inputs then question becomes if you can sort on read, or are supposed to do it after read, or if it is optional. etc.

Comment: @Morpfh: yip, this solution would scale normally even for bigger input (Eg. 100 numbers). To shift/swap they could also use memmove or a custom swap function `swap(int arr[], int idx1, int idx2)` as well.